# MySQL Query Error with Node Js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using MySQL with Node JS and I am detecting whether an existing user is already in the database. This code below is what I have been using:

```
var username = "RandomUsername";
var email = "RandomEmail@gmail.com";    
var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = " + username + " OR user_email = " + email;
connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (rows.length !== 0) {
            errors.push("Sorry, that email or username already being used.");
}
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cameroncjones4'' OR user_email = ''cameroncjones4''' at line 1
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
at Parser.write (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
at Protocol.write (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
at Connection.query (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/CameronJones/Desktop/NodeJS/LoginSystem/app.js:86:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:107:17)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:373:10)
at flow (_stream_readable.js:750:26)
at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:730:3)
at _stream_readable.js:717:7
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Help with solving this problem appreciated.

Comment: I don't beleive that error message came from that code -- you must have edited the error message before posting -- please post the original error message

Comment: Yeah, but in doing so you "fixed" the problems by adding the quotes which were causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `'` and `;` to your `SQL query`.

Try this:

```
var username = "RandomUsername";
var email = "RandomEmail@gmail.com";    
var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" + username + "' OR user_email = '" + email + "';";
```

And don't forget the `;` at the end of each query.

EDITED:

I create a database in order to reproduce your error and your error is definitely the quotes `'`.

Try copy/paste my code into your code and let me know the result of it. Off course you will need a connection object but I think you are already using one.

```
var username = "RandomUsername";
var email = "RandomEmail@gmail.com";
var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" + username + "' OR user_email = '" + email+ "'";

connection.connect();

connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (rows.length !== 0) {
      console.log(rows);
      connection.end();
    }else{
      console.log('Nothing match');
    }
});
```

My guess is when you try to put the single quotes you put double single quotes because your editor (atom? sublimeText?).

Comment: @CameronJones I reproduced your error and edited my answer, let me know if that solve it.